# Removing an object from an array using one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop

Possibly a very obvious question from a beginner:

If I have the following array...

```
var arr = 
  [
    {id: 1, item: "something", description: "something something"},
    {id: 2, item: "something else", description: "something different"},
    {id: 3, item: "something more", description: "more than something"}
  ]
```

... and wanted to delete a specific object within it by calling on the id (in this case by clicking on an div given the corresponding id)...

```
var thisItem = $(this).attr("id");
```

... could I do this without using a for loop to match `arr[i]` and `thisItem`? And if so, how? I'm going to have a big array so running a for-loop seems very heavy handed.

Thanks!

Comment: For latest browsers [`arr.splice(arr.findIndex(o => o.id === 2), 1);`](https://jsfiddle.net/54mLn6m3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery's `grep`

```
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
  return value.id != id;
});
```

Comment: This also works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering any array. This method takes a filtering function as its argument and runs it on every element of the original array. If the return value of this function is `false`, that element is filtered out of the new array that is returned. Original array is not affected.

```
var arr = 
  [
    {id: 1, item: "something", description: "something something"},
    {id: 2, item: "something else", description: "something different"},
    {id: 3, item: "something more", description: "more than something"}
  ];

function filterArray( id ){
  return arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.id != id;
  });//filter
}//filterArray()

console.log( filterArray(2) );
```

Comment: `array.filter` is the way to go

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS Solution:

```
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  item: "something",
  description: "something something"
}, {
  id: 2,
  item: "something else",
  description: "something different"
}, {
  id: 3,
  item: "something more",
  description: "more than something"
}];

var filtered = filterArrayByElemId(arr, 2);
console.log(filtered);

function filterArrayByElemId(arr, id) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id != id;
  });
}
```